# How do I remove extraneous data from JSON file that is not in any dictionary? (HTTP logs)

Tags: python, json

I am still new and learning so bear with me.

Okay - so I have HTTP logs (~100k+ records). I am trying to format it correctly to be used by JSON load function. Which I know will accept:

```
[ 
    { "k1":"v1" } 
    { "k2":"v2" }
    { "k3":"v3" }
]
```

My data is not currently in a list but looks like this:

```
2019-11-13T23:50:00Z    httplog    { "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":"v3" } 
2019-11-13T23:50:00Z    httplog    { "k4":"v4", "k5":"v5", "k6":"v6" }
.
.
.
```

etc. for 100k records.

What would be the best way to remove the extra information before the dictionaries begin on each line so that I may wrap it in a list and then be able to pass it to JSON load?

Thank you! Let me know if I didn't include enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
from io import StringIO
import json

log = StringIO("""\
2019-11-13T23:50:00Z    httplog    { "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":"v3" } 
2019-11-13T23:50:00Z    httplog    { "k4":"v4", "k5":"v5", "k6":"v6" }
""")

data = [json.loads(l.split('httplog')[-1].strip()) for l in log]
```

And `data` ends up being:

```
[{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}, {'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'v5', 'k6': 'v6'}]
```

Alternatively, if you can't reliably split the line on "httplog", but you do know that your data starts after the first "{", you could do:

```py
data = [json.loads(l[l.find('{'):].strip()) for l in log]
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I need. I can reliably split on "httplog". Awesome, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it 